# Count/Check first instances of entries in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

```
  id          | user_id        |      date_tracked
---------------------------------------------
 1001         |  1             | 10-10-2013
 1002         |  2             | 10-10-2013
 1003         |  3             | 10-10-2013
 1004         |  1             | 10-11-2013
 1005         |  2             | 10-12-2013
```

I have a table similar to this, which tracks a user and a date. I need to find how many first-time entries for users occurred on a selected date. This table is going to hold a significant amount of data, which is why I'd like to rely on a query to process this instead of a bunch of PHP loops.

i.e. on 10-11-2013, user 1 visited but not their first time, so return 0
on 10-10-2013, user 1 and 2 visited for their first time, so return 2.

Obviously, using a simple query can count the number of entries on a specified date, but what methodology will allow me to only count if the user_id is not present on a row prior.

The table is ordered by date, meaning that a more recent date should never have a smaller id than an older date.

Any ideas?? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Finding all "first time"-date, by user:

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(date_tracked) AS first_date
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
```

Counting "first time", for each date:

```
SELECT t.first_date, COUNT(*) AS nb
FROM (SELECT user_id, MIN(date_tracked) AS first_date
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id) t
GROUP BY t.first_date
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to Filipe,

Maybe this would be more suitable?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.date ='2013-8-27'
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM table t2
WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id
  AND t2.id < t1.id
);
```

Comment: Yes. i think i like this one better also. I updated my answer with an alternative and example.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT user_id, MIN(date_tracked)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY user_id

Answer (score 0):

For counting as one, if the user visits multiple times in the first day, you can do it in two ways:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id)
FROM user t1
WHERE t1.date_tracked = '2013-10-12' 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM user t2
    WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id
      AND t2.date_tracked < t1.date_tracked
    );

SELECT COUNT(user_id)
FROM user t1
WHERE t1.date_tracked ='2013-10-12'
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
  FROM user t2
  WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id
    AND t2.id < t1.id
);
```

I think i prefer the second, as it is much more cleaner by comparing ID's and not having to do the distinct.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9cdb4/6)</kbd>

Comment: I like the way this is formatted, but if the user logs in more than once on the same day this won't hold up.

Comment: If they login twice or more in that day, you want them to count as 1?

Comment: whether they log in more than once, it just needs to check the first time they log in throughout the entire database. This was checking the first date they visited, which wouldn't return the correct ID if they visited more than once in a day.

Answer (score 0):

By your tags I assume you want your answer in php as well. 
Just one query: shouldn't date 10-10-2013 return 3?
Anyway you can try this:

```
<?php
```

$dbConnect = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass)or die();

```
@mysqli_select_db($dbConnect, $dbname) or die();
$query = "SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE date_tracked = '$searchDate' AND (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tablename WHERE date_tracked < '$searchDate')=0";
$queryResult = @mysqli_query($dbConnect, $query) or die();
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($queryResult);
echo $rowCount . "<br/>";

mysqli_close($dbConnect);
```

?>